# C++: Constructor returns this as a nullptr

Tags: c++, pointers, null, this

I have a program which should add items to a linked list. I run a function that creates a new `Item` object with a constructor. The problem is that the constructor (after the user has input the different values) returns the `this`-pointer as a `nullptr`, and nothing is added to the list.

This function starts the add item-function:

```
void Items::addNewItem(){
    itemList->add(new Item(categoryBase->lastItemInUse++));
}
```

`itemList` is a pointer to a List object defined in the constructor in the `Items` class:

```
Items::Items(char* fname){
    itemList = new List(Sorted);
}
```

When the `new` keyword is used, this constructor is called:

```
Item::Item(int n) : NumElement(n) {
    char tekst[STRLEN];

    read("Salesman: ", tekst, STRLEN);
    salesman = new char[strlen(tekst) + 1];  strcpy(salesman, tekst);
    read("Title: ", tekst, STRLEN);
    title = new char[strlen(tekst) + 1];  strcpy(title, tekst);
    read("Description: ", tekst, STRLEN);
    description = new char[strlen(tekst) + 1];  strcpy(description, tekst);
    startTime = read("Start time for auction(ÅÅMMDDTTMM) ", 1, 23); //Use Frodes time.cpp and h.
    endTime  = read("End time for auction(ÅÅMMDDTTMM) ", startTime, 24);  //Use Frodes time.cpp and h.
    startPrice = read("Start price for auction ", MINPRICE, MAXPRICE);
    shipping = read("Shipping ", 0, MAXSHIPPING);
    increaseBid = read("Increase a Bid ", 1, MAXINCREASE);
    lastBid = bidTime = 0;          // Sets lastBid and bidTime to 0
    buyer = NULL;                   // buyer points to NULL until bid
    }
```

When I debug the program, I can see the `this`-pointer "filling" up with data, but when after everything is filled in, and the program jumps back to the `addNewItem()` function, the `this`-pointer is suddenly `NULL`.

Can anyone see where my mistake is?

Comment: Are you talking about two different `this` pointers?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You should try to give minimal verifiable code instead of giving it all. Also, note that debugger sometimes act little different than expected. Put some print statements wherever needed. BTW, constructors Never return any thing. So edit the post accordingly.